# Warning 634 and Warning 613 :MISRA

Tags: c++, lint, misra

I have two scenario where I am not able to resolve these warnings ..                        These are repetitive warnings

```
1) Warning 634: Strong type mismatch (type 'SPI_FSH_HANDLE') in equality or conditional 


            #define SPI_NULL NULL
            SPI_FSH_HANDLE  flash;
            if (flash != SPI_NULL)
```

I tried to check the NULL condition but still warnings persisted.

```
2)Warning 613: Possible use of null pointer 'flash' in left argument to operator '->'
```

Part of Code :

```
if (strstr(flash->name, "M25P")!= SPI_NULL)
```

How I can avoid both the warnings  ???

Answer (score 0):

The second should be fixable by testing `flash` before dereferencing it.

The first looks like a stupid warning. If you can't disable it, perhaps could be fixed by testing `if (flash)`, if MISRA doesn't have a stupid rule preventing that, or `if (flash != SPI_FSH_HANDLE(SPI_NULL))` otherwise. Or perhaps make `SPI_NULL` a constant of type `SPI_FSH_HANDLE` or `void*`, rather than an evil macro that (probably) expands to `0`.